# Duplicate tags: Duplicate and duplicate removal

Tags: support, synonym-request

We have both [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) and [duplicate-removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-removal) which seems to [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) the need for [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) tags.

Could we [duplicate-removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-removal) the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicate)?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this has happened, and I strongly disagree with this decision.

Questions about `duplicate-removal` in the context of databases/SQL are usually something completely different then questions about "just" duplicates.

Here is an example that should be tagged with `duplicate-removal`: [PostgresSQL how to delete duplicated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717426/postgressql-how-to-delete-duplicated-values)

A question which simply deals with getting rid of them in a SELECT statement: [How to replace duplicate cells with blanks/nulls in SQL server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628405/how-to-replace-duplicate-cells-with-blanks-nulls-in-sql-server-2008)

Queries dealing with duplicates usually involve using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` or some other SQL feature. *Deleting* duplicates however is a different topic especially if for example no single unique column (other then the ones the duplicates are defined by) can be used.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Couldn't we make a more specific tag like [sql-duplicate]?

Comment: We now have a [community dedicated to databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Hopefully this has resolved the confusion.